# The below code is not able to save the entered data in database in django

Tags: html, django, database

views.py

```
def contact_us(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formq = forms.querys(request.POST)
        if formq.is_valid():
            obj = query()
            obj.name = formq.cleaned_data['your_name']
            obj.email = formq.cleaned_data['your_email']
            obj.message = formq.cleaned_data['your_message']
            obj.save()
            return redirect(index)
    else :
        formq = forms.querys()
    return render(request, 'home/contact_us.html', {'formq': formq})
```

models.py

```
class query(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Email = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    Message = models.CharField(max_length=1500)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Name
```

forms.py

```
class querys(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=models.query
        fields = ['Name', 'Email','Message']
```

Please Help with how can I add the query in the database and view it on the admin page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple things that you need to see:

1. Since you are using ModelForm so you don't have to manually clean and save the data like you are doing.Calling `save()` method will do the job.
2. Moreover don't import entire forms and models. Import what is
   necessary. Don't import the entire file.
3. You can't redirect to url name without using `reverse`. Please look at this [reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse)

This view is valid if you are using `formq` object in template i.e `{{ formq }}`. If you are making custom html form then make sure the name of `<input>` are same as django form fields.Assuming views.py and forms.py are in the same location.

**views.py**

```
from .forms import querys
from django.urls import reverse
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect

def contact_us(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formq = querys(request.POST)
        if formq.is_valid():
            formq.save()
            return redirect(reverse(index))
        else:
            return render(request, 'home/contact_us.html', {'formq': formq})
    else:
        formq = querys()
        return render(request, 'home/contact_us.html', {'formq': formq})
```

Again assuming models.py and forms.py are in the same location.

**forms.py**

```
from .models import query

class querys(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=query
        fields = ['Name', 'Email','Message']
```